# Runge-Kutta method, the tables

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, runge-kutta-methods

I have a problem in [this](http://62.182.86.140/main/1539000/43a7a457b95e0443c75d23dc1b46fee7/J.%20C.%20Butcher%20-%20Numerical%20Methods%20for%20Ordinary%20Differential%20Equations-Wiley%20%282016%29.pdf) excellent book in the derivation of the Runge-Kutta methods,
The numerical analysis of  ODE.

> My wish is to understand how the data as in [*] below are obtained from item $(242a)$.

> What is the relationship between $\alpha$'s and $\beta$'s from $(242a)$ and $a$'s,$b$'s and $c$'s from the page $101$ ?

how have we created
the numbers $\frac{1}{\gamma(t)}$ and the polynomials $\Phi(t)$
in the table on the page $101$
in **oversimplified** terms ?

[*]
I would like to understand this on an example of this graph:

\/

why:
$\sum b_i c_i  ^2 = 1/3$

and the what does it tell us the shape itself of this graph ?

Comment: It is the identity for the coefficients of the Taylor term $f''(x)[f(x),f(x)]$. These are overall parts of the third order derivative. Butcher trees serve to shorten and simplify the Taylor expansions of the method and the exact solution.

Comment: @LutzLehmann Right. How have you come to $f''(x)[f(x),f(x)]$ from $\sum b_i c_i  ^2 = 1/3$ ?

Comment: It's the structure of the tree, two simple branches. The root gives the factor $b_i$ and $f''$ for two sub-trees, that the sub-trees are simple gives the factor $c_i$ twice, once for each sub-tree, and in the derivative the $f$ as direction vectors. In total this is a condition for the contained quadrature method, in the expansion of the exact solution it belongs to the third derivative, giving a Taylor factor $\frac1{3!}$, while in the expansion of the method it belongs to the second derivative of $f$ giving a factor $\frac1{2!}$, after cancelation a factor $\frac13$ remains.

Comment: @LutzLehmann I just don't follow why there appeared the divided difference $[f(x),f(x)]$ and why have you skipped one derivative of $f$ from $f$ itself up to the second derivative  $f''$ but you missed the first derivative ?

Comment: In this case I used the symbols just to indicate the linear arguments of the vector-valued symmetric bi-linear form $f''(x)$. There are only so many bracket symbols, so they have to serve different purposes, depending on context. As another example, the 5-stage 5th order method of Kutta does not work on systems because $f'(x)[f''(x)[f(x),f(x)]]$ is different from $f''(x)[f'(x)[f(x)],f(x)]$ in the system case, splitting up one order condition in the scalar case into two independent order conditions in the system case. One could invent different notation, like $\partial^2f(x;f(x)\odot f(x))$.

Comment: @LutzLehmann How have you derived the word **third** in your comment here: "it belongs to the third derivative," ?

Comment: In $x_{+1}=x+h\sum b_ik_i$ the second-order terms in $k_i$ become third-order terms in the next point $x_{+1}$. So on one side you have factor $\frac12$ and the combination of $b_i$, $a_{ij}$ and $c_l$, on the other side the fraction $\frac16$. Then cancel the common factors.

Comment: @LutzLehmann Well, but what about $x$ in $=x+...$: is there as well the factor $\frac{1}{2}$ so that the cancellation may be carried out ?

Comment: Yes. You have $k_i=f(x+Δ_ix)$ (where $Δ_ix=h\sum a_{ij}k_j$), and the third term in the Taylor expansion of the right side has the factor $\frac12$.

Comment: @LutzLehmann You now have $x_{+1}=x+h\sum b_i k_i=x+h\sum b_i f(x+h\sum a_{ij}k_j)$. So please what is the third term of this right hand side of the Taylor expansion ?

Comment: In most cases a direct, unqualified reference references the most immediate object, here the formula $k_i=f(x+Δ_ix)=f(x)+f'(x)Δ_ix+\frac12f''(x)[Δ_ix,Δ_ix]+...$, where you find the factor $\frac12$ in the third term.

Comment: @LutzLehmann In your -5th comment above you have $x_{+1}=x+h\sum b_i k_i$ but then you turn into $f(x+\Delta_i x)=f(x+h\sum_j a_{ij} k_j)$. Why are you allowed to add the symbol $f$ to that r.h.s. expression **and** change $\sum_i b_i k_i$ to $\sum_j a_{ij} k_j)$ ? I believe that your steps and explanations are indeed correct but I have from time to time a difficulty to grasp them properly. Thank you for your kind patience.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is mainly due to a misunderstanding of a section change. The $c_i,a_{ij},b_i$ belong indeed to the Butcher tableau of a Runge-Kutta one-step method.
The $\alpha_i$, $\beta_i$ however are taken from the next section on linear multi-step methods. While there is some overlap in the lower-order methods, in general these methods and their theory are different.

---

As to the comment/bounty, the RK methods evaluate several expressions of the form $X_{..}=x_n+h\sum \text{coeff}_{..,j}k_j$. In the stages these are

$$
X_i=x_n+h\sum_ja_{ij}k_j
$$
and the point for the next step
$$
x_{n+1}=x_n+h\sum_ib_ik_i.
$$
The, possibly recursive, connection of the $k_i$ and $X_i$ is that
$$
k_i=f(X_i).
$$

---

The $\gamma(\tau)=\tau!$ also belongs to the RK methods, to their order conditions, or more precisely, the Taylor expansion of the exact solution. The term $F(\tau)$ as part of the Taylor expansion has order $|\tau|$. As such it has the common factor $\frac{h^{|\tau|}}{(|\tau|)!}$ over all terms of the same order. But in the construction of this expansion there can be multiple paths to obtain the same term, resulting in some multiplicity $c(\tau)$. On the other side, the Taylor expansion of the RK method will also result in purely numerical factors, giving the coefficient $\frac{h^{|\tau|}}{\sigma(\tau)}$. Apparently $c(\tau)$ divides into $(|\tau|)!$ and $\sigma(\tau)$ divides into the remaining product, so it can be extracted via $\frac{c(\tau)}{(|\tau|)!}=\frac1{\sigma(\tau)\tau!}$

Thus Taylor expansion
$$
x(t+h)=x(t)+\sum_{\tau}\frac{h^{|\tau|}}{\sigma(\tau)\tau!}F(\tau)(x(t))
$$
and method expansion
$$
x_{n+1}=x_n+\sum_\tau\frac{h^{|\tau|}}{\sigma(\tau)}\Phi(\tau)F(\tau)(x_n)
$$
where $F(\tau)$ is the combination of derivatives of $f$ corresponding to the tree $\tau$ and $\Phi(\tau)$ the polynomial in the method coefficients for the same tree.

For the example of $\tau=\backslash/=[[][]]$ you get, mostly mechanically, $\Phi(\backslash/)=\sum b_ic_i^2$ and $F(\backslash/)=f''[f,f]$. The factors are $(\backslash/)!=\gamma(\backslash/)=3\cdot 1\cdot 1=3$ and $\sigma(\backslash/)=3!/3=2$.